# grails command has error

Tags: grails, groovy, openbox

when I enter grails upgrade command, below error raised:

```
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)

java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeProfile(GrailsCli.groovy:516)
at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeApplication(GrailsCli.groovy:307)  
at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:270)
at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null
```

what is the problem? what is the solution?

Comment: Can you try with `--verbose`

Comment: It has same result, I use this command for run openbox project in github @MikeW

Comment: Were you connected to the internet?

Comment: @JamesKleeh yeah, I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

My project was grails 1.3.9 and I installed grails 3.3.5

I install grails 1.3.9 in my system and it's be ok